# I have created my first Spring boot project with 3.2.1 Springboot version and JPA with MySQL database. I am trying to get the table using REST API

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, pom.xml, mysql-connector, jparepository

The table is created but the data is not getting inserted inside the table. The queries show a success of the insert statements but couldn't get the data in output.

Please help me as this is my first ever Spring boot application as I am new to this.

Many Thanks in advance :)

Here is my stack trace statement:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIT9h.png)

Here is my application.properties file:

[application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiafO.png)

I tried changing the application.properties file based on Stack overflow suggestions after reading a few posts but it didn't work. Initially I was not even able to create a table but after I saw in stack overflow that we need to change the Dialect properties in application.properties as per SQL version, table was created but now data is not getting inserted. [Table created and even used REST API to call it and it's successful.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDqkF.png)

Comment: Do you also run the .executeUpdate() for your statements? Please share the code how you insert the data into the database.

Comment: Student student1 = new Student("Aparna","Kumari","aparna.kumari@gmail.com");
  studentRepository.save(student1);

This way I am inserting the data into database in my main file I have written the code

Comment: Yes, and we need to see the code from inside of your save() method. There could be the problem. Please provide the code that shows how you are saving to the database.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to define a repository that extends JpaRepository. Example:

   ```
   @Repository
    public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, String> {

    }
   ```
2. Define a service class and use the repo already defined to insert a student, as shown below:

   ```
     @RequiredArgsConstructor
     @Service
     public class StudentService {

     private final StudentRepository studentRepo;
     public void insert(Student student) {
        studentRepo.save(student);
     }

     }
   ```
3. Define a controller class and expose an API endpoint to add students.

Example:

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/v1/students")
public class StudentController {
private final StudentService studentService;
@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Student> newStudent(@RequestBody @Valid Student student) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(studentService.insert(student));
    }

}
```

Make sure you're connecting to the appropriate database and using the correct table name.

Comment: I don't think you need the `@RequiredArgsConstructor` annotation. That is probably a lombok annotation placed there by accident.